# jquery plugin .append .each and a uniqe id

Tags: jquery, each

Im trying to create a simple plugin

the below code adds each **style** tag inside header attribute. the style tag contains *CSS* animation and the animation name is **animate**

```js
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.plugin = function( options ) {

        this.each(function() {

            var keyFrames = "@keyframes animate {0%{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}100%{transform:translate3d(-250px,0,0)}}";
            $("<style type='text/css'>" + keyFrames + "</style>").appendTo($("head"));
        });
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

$( ".animation" ).plugin({});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div class="animation">dsdsd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but im trying to make so each time it adds a different animation name. for example...
this doesn't work

```js
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.plugin = function( options ) {

        this.each(function() {
            
            var counter = 1;
            
            var keyFrames = "@keyframes animate" + counter++ " {0%{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}100%{transform:translate3d(-250px,0,0)}}";
            $("<style type='text/css'>" + keyFrames + "</style>").appendTo($("head"));
        });
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

$( ".animation" ).plugin({});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div class="animation">dsdsd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `counter++ +"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code, you see that there is an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string.` This is your first clue on where to actually look (some place that you've used a string).

If you look at this line: `var keyFrames = "@keyframes animate" + counter++ " {0%{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}100%{transform:translate3d(-250px,0,0)}}";`, your issue is you have `counter++` but don't concatenate anything after that. Your code should be the following:

```js
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.plugin = function( options ) {

        this.each(function() {
            
            var counter = 1;
            
            var keyFrames = "@keyframes animate" + counter++ + " {0%{transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}100%{transform:translate3d(-250px,0,0)}}";
            $("<style type='text/css'>" + keyFrames + "</style>").appendTo($("head"));
        });
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

$( ".animation" ).plugin({});
```

```html
<html> 
<body> 
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> <div class="animation">dsdsd</div> </body> </html>
```